# Ruby regular expression using variable name

Tags: ruby, regex

Is is possible to create/use a regular expression pattern in ruby that is based on the value of a variable name?

For instance, we all know we can do the following with Ruby strings:

```
str = "my string"
str2 = "This is #{str}" # => "This is my string"
```

I'd like to do the same thing with regular expressions:

```
var = "Value"
str = "a test Value"
str.gsub( /#{var}/, 'foo' ) # => "a test foo"
```

Obviously that doesn't work as listed, I only put it there as an example to show what I'd like to do.  I need to regexp match based on the value of a variable's content.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

The code you think doesn't work, does:

```
var = "Value"
str = "a test Value"
p str.gsub( /#{var}/, 'foo' )   # => "a test foo"
```

Things get more interesting if var can contain regular expression meta-characters.  If it does and you want those matacharacters to do what they usually do in a regular expression, then the same gsub will work:

```
var = "Value|a|test"
str = "a test Value"
str.gsub( /#{var}/, 'foo' ) # => "foo foo foo"
```

However, if your search string contains metacharacters and you do *not* want them interpreted as metacharacters, then use Regexp.escape like this:

```
var = "*This*"
str = "*This* is a string"
p str.gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(var)}/, 'foo' )
# => "foo is a string"
```

Or just give gsub a string instead of a regular expression.  In MRI >= 1.8.7, gsub will treat a string replacement argument as a plain string, not a regular expression:

```
var = "*This*"
str = "*This* is a string"
p str.gsub(var, 'foo' ) # => "foo is a string"
```

(It used to be that a string replacement argument to gsub was automatically converted to a regular expression.  I know it was that way in 1.6.  I don't recall which version introduced the change).

As noted in other answers, you can use Regexp.new as an alternative to interpolation:

```
var = "*This*"
str = "*This* is a string"
p str.gsub(Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(var)), 'foo' )
# => "foo is a string"
```

Comment: The hint on Regexp.escape was just what I didn't know I needed. Thanks!

Comment: regxPlayerVariable = '(.*?)=.*?document\.getElementById\(#{pluginPlayeVariable}\)' in this i applied all above but these are not working.

Comment: @SSP It might be good to explain the trouble in a separate question.

Answer (score 13):

It works, but you need to use `gsub!` or assign the return to another variable

```
var = "Value"
str = "a test Value"
str.gsub!( /#{var}/, 'foo' )  # Or this: new_str = str.gsub( /#{var}/, 'foo' )
puts str
```

Answer (score 11):

#### Yes

---

```
str.gsub Regexp.new(var), 'foo'
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use regular expressions through variables in ruby:

```
var = /Value/
str = "a test Value"
str.gsub( /#{var}/, 'foo' )
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this only has downvotes. I tried it and it works, even though you don't need the regex slashes in both the `var` variable and gsub's first parameter.

Comment: I think the point of the slashes in gsub was to show that a regex can contain a variable which is itself a regex. The variable doesn't have to be string type (and in fact, regex is better for reasons outlined in Wayne's answer).

Answer (score 3):

```
str.gsub( Regexp.new("#{var}"), 'foo' )
```

Comment: I think it's `Regexp`

Comment: Yes, it is `Regexp` https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html