# Ruby Match - escape a string with special characters

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have written the following code to match a service name in my property file :-

```
service = properties.match(/^com\.google\.([#{serviceName}]+)\.public$/)
```

This code works fine when I give any `serviceName` but fails if the `serviceName` has a `-` in between

Eg - `common-api`

Error:

```
empty range in char class: /^com\.google\.([common-api]+)\.public$/ (SyntaxError)
```

Any idea how can i escape the whole string from regex evaluation?

Comment: Why are you matching the string with a character class using the characters of your name string?

Comment: A quick google search returns [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268421/ruby-regular-expression-using-variable-name).

Comment: Are you looking for [Regexp::escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want [`Regexp.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-escape):

```
service = properties.match(/^com\.google\.(#{Regexp.escape(serviceName)})\.public$/)
```

Additionally, you had surrounded your inclusion of `serviceName` with a `[...]+`, which means more than one character from this list of characters in `[...]`.

E.g. This regexp `[commonapi]+` accepts `moconaipimdconn`, or indeed any length string that contained some characters from the service name you actually wanted to capture.

Comment: Still returns the same error ...

Comment: Updated my answer, I didn't notice that you had a `[...]+` enclosing the `serviceName`, which was an additional problem.