# Way to DRY ruby regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this regex to check if a string is of format *date, two or three dots ,date*

`/\A(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4})...?(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4})\z/`

As you can see, the date matching group `\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}` is repeated.

Is there a regex-native or a general ruby programming way to assign this group to a variable and then use it in the regex, rather than the actual group, giving me something like `/\A<var>...?<var>\z/`?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268421/ruby-regular-expression-using-variable-name ?

Comment: That one is just too confusing, Roney Michael's answer covers what I need.

Comment: After checking his answer, I still believe these are duplicates. Also, you said *two or three dots*, and Roney Michael uses `/\A(#{re1})...?(#{re1})\z/` instead of `/\A(#{re1})\.{2,3}(#{re1})\z/`. `.` matches *any character*, and `\.` matches a literal period. And I do not get the idea of adding single shorthand character classes into character classes (e.g. `[\w]+` when `\w+` will suffice).

Comment: I can not judge whether questions are duplicates, but the dot part is spot on - `\.{2,3}` should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex concatenation should do the trick.

From the discussion [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/59614):

```
irb(main):001:0> re1 = re1 = /[\w]+/
=> /[\w]+/
irb(main):002:0> re2 = /[\d]+/
=> /[\d]+/
irb(main):003:0> re3 = /#{re1}[\s]+#{re2}/
=> /(?-mix:[\w]+)[\s]+(?-mix:[\d]+)/
irb(main):004:0> "Foo 123".match(re3).to_s
=> "Foo 123"
```

---

For your code specifically:

```
irb(main):001:0> re1 = /\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}/
=> /\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}/
irb(main):002:0> re2 = /\A(#{re1})...?(#{re1})\z/
=> /\A((?-mix:\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}))...?((?-mix:\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}))\z/
```

..and then use re2 as desired.

Comment: Regex concatenation ftw!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with regular ruby

```
date_regex = /\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}/
/\A(#{date_regex})...?(#{date_regex})\z/
```